# What's wrong with my logic, I can't determine if there are 3 in a row from the left or the bottom of the grid?

Tags: java, android, logic

So I'm trying to check whether there are 3 of the same colour tiles in a row both vertically and horizontally. This is working for tiles that are horizontal from the left but not the right. It's also working for the tiles that are aligned from the top but not the bottom.

Basically I've got a 4BY4 grid where each tile can be changed to either, red, white, or grey. Something is wrong with my logic and I just can't pick it out!!

Here is the code that Im using to determine whether there are 3 in a row! `gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white` - This will just check if the returned RDC is white. At the moment just trying to get the logic correct, I haven't added code to check if the RDC is red yet.

```
public void checkWinner(){
    //CHECK FOR HORIZONTAL
    for(int i=0;i<16;i+=4){
        if(gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
                && gridArray[i+1].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
                && gridArray[i+2].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
        ){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THREE IN A ROW HORIZONTALLY",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("MyApp","3 in row horizontally");
        }
        
    }
    

    //CHECK FOR VERTICAL
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            if(gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
            && gridArray[i+4].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
            && gridArray[i+8].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
//          && gridArray[i+12].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
//          || 
//          gridArray[i+12].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
//          && gridArray[i+8].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
//          && gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
            ){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THREE IN A ROW VERTICALLY",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("MyApp","3 in row vertically");
            }
        }
    }
```

So at the moment if I get 3 tiles in a row FROM THE LEFT OF THE GRID then it will display a `toast` BUT **if I get 3 in a row from the RIGHT SIDE OF THE GRID** It won't  show the toast? This is the same with the vertically aligned tiles (I'll explain after this image).

### Aligned from the left

So this is the image where there are 3 tiles horizontally aligned from the left:

[image: Aligned from the left]

### Aligned from the right:

And here is an image where there are 3 tiles aligned horizontally from the right:
[image: Aligned from the right]

### Images of the vertically aligned tiles from the TOP:

[image: aligned from the top]

### Aligned from the bottom

For some reason it won't check if there are 3 aligned vertically from the bottom of the grid, only the top?!

[image: aligned from the bottom]

Comment: Is there some constraint that is requiring you to use a 1D array?

Comment: Well I mean, if it works then why do say, a 2d or 3d array?  @ChiefTwoPencils - But i do understand where you're coming from.

Comment: Does it work if you're posting a question here ;) ?

Comment: No it doesn't haha! But some answers below have fixed the issues I was having :) @piezol

Comment: The reason for a 2D array is it's more representative of the structure. You're forcing an inflexible design with the hard coding of numbers which is a result of the 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the vertical check,

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
```

Why? Because we have two rows that can have a column with three consecutive cells of the same color. Row 1 and row 2.

The most reliable way to find an error in a loop is to draw a table on paper and go through each iteration. But there are some other problems with your code. This is a one-dimensional array representing a two-dimensional problem. It's illogical and error-prone. Also, you are hard-coding numbers when you should be writing adaptable code. What if you need to change it to a five-by-five grid?

Comment: Awesome this solved this vertical alignment issue :)

Comment: ahh. I really should change it to a 2D array to prevent any other errors? But I mean I've got it too work now! But yes you're right, I may need to change it too a 5by5 grid in the future. But then again if I did want a 5by5 all I'd need to do is create another method `check5winner()` and simply copy my other method and increment the numbers by the respective amounts.

Comment: To just make another method for 5by5 is a poor design choice, because we would have duplicated code. If we need to change something else (say the color to check), we now need to fix two places (and we often forget all the places to fix so we introduce new bugs with each change).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i+=4){
    if(gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
            && gridArray[i+1].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
            && gridArray[i+2].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
    ){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THREE IN A ROW HORIZONTALLY",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("MyApp","3 in row horizontally");
    }

}
```

In this loop you start checking for i == 0, i == 4, i == 8, i == 12.
In your example 1,2,3 are white, but you'll never actually check that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to determin if there are three blocks of the same color is fundamentally wrong. Firsty, you should have 2-d array rather then 1-d, you have now, since it would be easily extendable.

```
for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<COLUMNS;j++){

         int color=gridArray[i][j++];
         int count=1;

          while(color==gridArray[i][j++]){
             count++;
             if(count>=MAX_SAME_COLOR){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),MAX_SAME_COLOR+" IN A ROW HORIZONTALLY",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("MyApp",MAX_SAME_COLOR+" in row horizontally");
               }
           }

    }
}
```

if you just changed dimensions you could easily get if there are three blocks of the same color vertically as well.

Comment: It **does check** if they are in a row. Take a closer look. Once a different color is encountered it will exit while loop and count will be reset to "1". Look closer before you comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i+=4){
        if((gridArray[i].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
                && gridArray[i+1].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
                && gridArray[i+2].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
        )
       ||
        (gridArray[i+1].getRDC() == R.drawable.white 
                && gridArray[i+2].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
                && gridArray[i+3].getRDC() == R.drawable.white
        )){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THREE IN A ROW HORIZONTALLY",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("MyApp","3 in row horizontally");
        }

    }
```